# Trouble with setting values in a class to .Empty

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program that uses Microsoft access and i'm having trouble with setting a value in a class to .Empty. It works fine with a string but it does not work with int or DateTime, i'm wondering what could I use instead?

```
        public CustomerData()
    {
        FirstName = string.Empty;
        LastName = string.Empty;
        Company = string.Empty;
        Question1 = string.Empty;
        Question2 = string.Empty;
        Question3 = string.Empty;
        Question4 = string.Empty;
        Question5 = int.Empty; 
        FeedbackComments = string.Empty;
        FDate = DateTime.Empty; 
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with null though? Seems like a lot of administration in order to skip some null checks, that you will probably need to do anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Empty` property for DateTime class, probably you should use `MinValue;` property to initialize the date time variable. which will initialize the variable with `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`. So the code for this would be

```
FDate = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Read more about [`DateTime.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), Same in the case of `int.Empty`, you can use `0` instead or `int.MinValue` which will give you `-2147483648`

Comment: Note that DateTime and int are structs, so they will always have a value. They will be initialized with DateTime.MinValue and 0 respectivally. You don't have to do that explicitly in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

A `DateTime` object is of different type from a `String` object and there isn't any implicit conversion between them. Hence, you can't assign a `String` value to a variable that can hold `DateTime` values. I would say that you have two otpions

- Use the `DateTime.MinValue`, `FDate = DateTime.MinValue`.
- Redeclare the type of value as `DateTime?` and set the value of `null`.

Comment: FYI "That being said" is similar to "however" in meaning. Since both the second and first sentences are working towards the same point, it doesn't make sense here. Apologies for the long explanation if removing my edit was unintentional.

Comment: @john I was editing my post at this moment :( I changed it to Hence. I think that now is more correct. Apologies for the bad use. Thanks !